# T-Test or U-Test

Tags: t-test, nonparametric, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, group-differences

I have a number of items that are based on a Likert scale, with values ranging from 1 = not at all to 5 = very much so. I would like to compare answers to these questions between two groups. I would like to analyze each question separately. To my understanding, I need to use the Mann–Whitney U test, because I have ordinal data. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. Though defaulting to a Mann–Whitney $U$ test is not a requirement. In general, you correctly note that you should treat Likert-type *item* responses as ordinal data (review this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357332/appropriate-to-do-t-tests-on-ordinal-or-binary-data) for more information). Ordinal data often do not meet the assumptions of the standard $t$-test. The issue is the *central tendency* (i.e., mean) of your ordinal measure. We can't assume values center around a particular value, or even the item's midpoint. Likert-type measures discriminate based upon the item's *ranking* of values. Numerical quantities map to ordered responses; the "order" is often arbitrarily chosen by the designer of the survey instrument. For instance, values from 1–5 represent arbitrary codes (i.e., labels). A Mann-Whitney $U$ test, or any other "rank-based" test, does not depend on the numeric labels used to order the categories (review this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255367/what-differentiates-the-wilcoxon-test-from-t-test-regarding-ordinal-variables) for more information). In fact, the test is invariant to the arbitrary labels assigned to the categories, so long as the ranking of responses is preserved.